# Barplots with column names

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have this dataset :

```
 dat<-read.table(text = "pl     Freq
             Abid     23
             Berl     54
             Cara     54
             Daka     10",header=T)
```

I am trying to have an histogram with the name of each columns (under the columns (i.e. "pl" informations)  and the columns sorted in decreasing order...
I tried a lot of ordering method, but :

```
 barplot(dat$freq)
```

Seems to not be the good way...

I you have any idea that would be helpfull !

Cheers,

R.

Comment: `with(dat[order(dat$Freq), ], barplot(Freq, names.arg = pl))`

Comment: Yes ! It is exactly that  for the labels of the columns ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

I beieve this is what you are looking for:

```
barplot(dat$Freq, names.arg = dat$pl)
```

And if you want to have the barplot sorted according to their frequencies:

```
dat <- dat[order(dat$Freq, decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

Thomas